# How to return to academia after "don't walk, run"?

Tags: advisor, career-path

It seems the phrase "don't walk, run!" [is somewhat of a meme](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/975/dont-walk-dont-run-either) on this site. It roughly means "leave your current advisor/university/PI/whatever and don't look back".

While this at times may be good advice, although most often controversial, I'm wondering how one should handle the running if one *remains* willing to work in academia. (Just somewhere else) I mean, the suggestion sounds a lot like 'burning bridges' (with only one person at best, but with an entire department at the worst). Burning bridges is commonly understood to be a quick way to kill your career.

So, I'd like to have a well-thought answer to the question:

- How (if it even can be done!) can I run from an abusive professional relation or otherwise unmaintainable position *without ruining my career*?

Perhaps this is already explained in some post given the "don't walk, run!" advice, but I think it is worthwhile to have answers to this particular question. Advice from academics who have in fact 'ran away' and proceeded within academia is very much appreciated. (this would at least answer whether it can be done)

---

Finally, to prevent any confusion: I'm currently *not* in an abusive professional relation or otherwise unmaintainable position. I'm merely interested in how one should act, for future readers in that situation. (Who knows, I could even be unfortunate enough to end up in such a situation one day!)

---

To clarify, this is a question asking for general advice for after leaving. To be clear, the 'running part' refers to 'not leaving in a nice and orderly manner' (Imagine a grad student literally running away from the campus, leaving a trail of thesis papers behind, if that helps). Most answers to the question suggested as duplicate essentially tell to 'walk', but here I have assumed to have already 'run' (whether that is a good idea is besides the point) and with that given, want to know what the best course of action is and the advice on the other question is too late.

Comment: Personally, I never liked that kind of advice, said in such a blunt way. Along my career I saw a couple of critical cases where the student had to walk away from an abusive adviser, and these required quite delicate negotiations between the former adviser, the PhD programme chair and the new adviser. The students had to start with a new research topic with the same deadline for graduation (that given by the funding), causing additional stress. None of the students remained in academia.I think that such an advice can be given only when knowing very well the context and the required procedure.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano: Of course there are going to be difficulties.  But what's the alternative?  Do you believe that things would have been better if the student had stayed with the abusive adviser?

Comment: @NateEldredge I think Massimo Ortolano suggests that sometimes 'walking away' (i.e. discussing the matter, usually with help of a university appointed mediator), is sometimes preferable to 'running'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change schools/advisors without making my advisor angry?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13164/how-do-i-change-schools-advisors-without-making-my-advisor-angry)

Comment: @NateEldredge I disagree on the dupe. This is a question asking for general advice for _after_ leaving. To be clear, the 'running part' refers to 'not leaving in a nice and orderly manner' (Imagine a grad student literally running away from the campus, leaving a trail of thesis papers behind, if that helps). Most answers to that question essentially tell to 'walk', but here I have assumed to have already 'run' (whether that is a good idea is besides the point) and with that given, want to know what the best course of action is and the advice on the other question is too late.

Comment: @NateEldredge No, but at least by walking and not running away they could finish their PhD. Had they run, they'd have never completed their PhD. In one case I suggested a student to suck it up until the end of their PhD, to avoid any future consequence, and the strategy worked. So, what I'm suggesting is to tread carefully: there are maybe countries where you can run, but others where running would simply destroy any chance of completing the PhD. I run from my former PhD adviser when I had already secured a permanent position, but I had to endure anyway the consequences for more than 10 years.

Comment: We also have another famous phrase: Don't run, walk!

Comment: Burning bridges with the "right" (actually, wrong) people could maybe even help your career, as it can be a sign that you recognize some bad behavior and are able to get yourself out of a bad situation instead of enabling people that might not have the best standing in the community anyway.

Comment: @skymningen Perhaps. But how will anyone recognize that when you've 'blown up' a large part of your professional network?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

“Don’t walk, run” is a shorthand for taking immediate action to extricate oneself from a rapidly deteriorating situation.

Note that this may not require leaving academia altogether, or even one’s current institution. You may be able to find a workable solution where you are by switching projects, advisors, or departments, as appropriate.

But sometimes it **is** necessary to leave, for economic, personal, or medical reasons. You may want to return. In that case, it’s not really all that different from other cases. The critical step is explaining to whom ever you’d like to hire or admit you that whatever situation caused your previous departure will not affect the present situation. You’ll need to make that case clearly and convincingly so as to reduce the “risk level” of your potential boss. If you can’t make that case, then you may want to reevaluate if returning is the right move at the present time.

Comment: Your advice on what to consider when 'returning' is useful. I do wonder what would be wise in a particular situation: what if your only real problem was with one person, but you did have 'radio silence' during the time you were 'absent' after leaving rather abruptly, should/must you contact the university and/or explain your motives for the abrupt leave and return (just explain, no need to _justify_ yourselves I think)? (how to do this if this is wise seems out of scope, but the _degree of 'recontact' with your previous 'problem'_ is on-scope, I think)

Comment: Also, I explicitly take 'running' to mean leaving _very_ abruptly, bordering on sudden disappearance. I'm not sure whether you definition of the phrase agrees on this. Could you explain?

Comment: Just running away is very problematic, especially if you’re getting paid by the university. You need to take the time to make sure things are squared away. “Don’t walk, run” does not mean “drop everything and go” unless your life is literally in danger.

Comment: Well, one reason for asking this question is that how exactly one should 'run' isn't entirely clear to me, so I simply assumed the worst possible method. But I suppose if one can prevent this, this should be done